# Julia - Use mock to test database query

Tags: unit-testing, julia

I would like to test that a function, doing a request on a database and returning the answer parsed. I don't want to do a real call to my database, because the data in my database will change, so I want to mock it.

I did an example here follow. How can I mock the LibPQ.Connection object? Because otherwise I have to pass a real connection object, but I don't use it as I mock the libPQ.execute?
I can not use nothing as sugested in my example, because the function libPQ.execute expects an object of type libPQ.connection, it is not working with nothing.

```
using Test
using Pretend
using LibPQ
using DataFrames

function function_to_test(conn::LibPQ.Connection)::MyStruct
    sql = "select * from my_table;"

    result = execute(conn, sql)

    # Parse my result and insert it into my struct

    return my_struct
end


Pretend.activate()
@testset verbose = true "Test my function" begin
    @testset "Mock LibPQ.execute" begin
        conn = nothing

        @mockable LibPQ.execute(conn::LibPQ.Connection, query::String)

        fake_execute(::Nothing, ::String) = [Dict("some_string" => "string", "some_int" => 234)]
        apply(execute => fake_execute) do
            @test typeof(function_to_test(conn)) == MyStruct
        end
    end
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function you want to test **must** get a `LibPQ.connection` object as an input. You specify that by saying `conn::LibPQ.Connection` in the function definition.

If that's not what you want to test, my suggestion would be to separate the database querying and the parsing.

```
# getting the object to parse
function get_data(conn::LibPQ.Connection)
    # ...
    return stuff
end

# parsing stuff
function function_to_test(stuff)::MyStruct
    # Parse my result and insert it into my struct

    return my_struct
end

# in the actual code you can then do
get_data(conn) |> function_to_test
```

...and in the test you can hard-code a `stuff` object and feed it to the `function_to_test` function.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've already mocked the execute, so data changing in your database would not matter. So, assuming you can at least create a valid connection during your tests this approach should work.

If you'd rather avoid creating a connection altogether then you would really only be testing parsing a dictionary to your struct.

```
@testset "Test my function" begin
    @testset "Parse db_result to my_struct" begin
        db_result = [Dict("some_string" => "string", "some_int" => 234)]
        @test typeof(MyStruct(db_result)) == MyStruct
    end
end
```

Comment: Thank you for your response. I agree with your response, but then I am not testing my function, but a separate implementation of my function.

My idea with the mock is also to test that the sql query on the mock is as expected. with something like
`called_exactly_once(executer, "select * from my_table;")`